# running another system project

Tags: android, linux, kotlin

I wrote a project in Windows,I changed the system to Linux, I get this error when I try to run my projects on Linux, I did a lot of searching but did not find any results, please help me

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.novinshop_project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you imported compose dependencies in the project??

Comment: @praveen I added libraries

Comment: First make sure that line ending in your files are correct. Windows `CRLF` and Linux `LF`

Comment: @vahid I did not get it

Comment: `CRLF` and `LF` are used to note the termination of a line in a file. You can google about it and read more. Windows and Linux treat line endings differently. This might not be the issue you are facing but just double check. Make sure that all your files have proper line endings based on your OS. You can simply configure this is your IDE. Usually the IDE shows the line ending at the bottom right corner.